# Syntax errors in Rails ActionMailer implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm trying to implement sending a notification email to myself from a simple Ruby on Rails service.  I've been following the guide on using ActionMailer at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html and the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html  I've essentially copy/pasted the code from the guides, but I get a bunch of syntax errors when I try to run it.

I've searched around, but haven't come across anyone with the same problem.  Given that and my lack of experience with Rails and Ruby, I suspect I may be missing something fundamental.

This is my mailer:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: 'info@mydomain.com'

  def uploadNotification
    mail(to: "jim@mydomain.com", subject: "Upload Notification")
  end
end
```

and I'm calling it like this:

```
NotificationMailer.uploadNotification.send
```

When the app tries to call the method, I get these errors:

```
SyntaxError (/Users/jimmcgowan/Sites/RoR/upload/app/models/notification_mailer.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
default from: 'info@mydomain.com'
             ^
/Users/jimmcgowan/Sites/RoR/upload/app/models/notification_mailer.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
mail(to: "jim@mmydomain.com", subject: "Upload Notification")
        ^
/Users/jimmcgowan/Sites/RoR/upload/app/models/notification_mailer.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
mail(to: "jim@mmydomain.com", subject: "Upload Notification")
                              ^
/Users/jimmcgowan/Sites/RoR/upload/app/models/notification_mailer.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND):
```

To try to make a simpler test, I removed the 'default from:' line, replaced the mail() call inside the uploadNotification method with a simple log, and changed the calling code to just NotificationMailer.uploadNotification.  However, that caused a NoMethodError instead.

Can anyone give me some pointers on where I'm going wrong?

**Update**

It seems that bgates answer is correct, and this is caused by syntactic differences version 1.8 and 1.9 of Ruby.  However, upgrading the Ruby installation on my hosted virtual server (running an old version of Suse), was impractical, so instead I re-wrote the class to be Ruby 1.8 compliant.  For the sake of the archives, here is the working version:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def uploadNotification
    from "My Server <info@mydomain.com>"
    recipients "jim@mydomain.com"
    subject "New Notification"
  end
end
```

And I call it like this:

```
NotificationMailer.deliver_uploadNotification
```

Comment: ruby never uses camelcase as a convention. `uploadNotification` should instead be `upload_notification`

Comment: I tried restarting the server, also switched to `upload_notification` as the method name, but same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things it's complaining about used to be syntax errors in Ruby 1.8.x. If you type

```
$ ruby -v
```

at the command line, and you get a number less than 1.9, you need to update your Ruby to a newer version.

Comment: This could be the issue, I have 1.8.7.  But since I'm on OS X, it seems upgrading requires a little work.  The site for the OSX GUI version of RVM seems to be down at the moment, but once it is back up I'll update Ruby and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "Mydomain <info@mydomain.com>",
            return_path: "Mydomain <info@mydomain.com>"

    def upload_notification
      mail(:to => "jim@mydomain.com", 
           :subject => "Upload Notification")
    end
end
```

and then calling it with .deliver instead of .send

```
NotificationMailer.upload_notification.deliver
```

Comment: I still get the syntax error on the colon in the `default from:` line, though it seems OK now with the syntax in the mail() call. I'll try again after I update Ruby.